# passing parameters to functions returning promises in a chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've a bunch of functions expecting parameters and returning promises, not sure how can I pass individual params to each one in the chain.

```
fs.readFile('./img/thumbnail.png', function(error, data) {
    module.create(body)
        .then(module.uploadImage) //expects collection.uploadImage(data);
        .then(module.requestInfo)
});
```

How can I make promises pass `data` to `module.uploadImage` as the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is known at the time you enter the function, you can use `.bind()`:

```
fs.readFile('./img/thumbnail.png', function(error, data) {
    module.create(body)
        .then(module.uploadImage.bind(module, data))
        .then(module.requestInfo)
});
```

See the [description of `.bind()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more details.

---

You can of course, always just create your own wrapper function that lets you pass anything you want, including computed parameters:

```
fs.readFile('./img/thumbnail.png', function(error, data) {
    module.create(body).then(function() {
        return module.uploadImage(data);
    }).then(module.requestInfo)
});
```

P.S. Please don't ignore error checking on your `fs.readFile()` callback.

Comment: question, I was wondering about missing return statement, but the other answer worked for me without the return statement in `return module.uploadImage(data)`, so is it required or not?

Comment: In the first code block in my answer, the return value from calling `module.uploadImage(data)` is automatically returned already.  In the second code block in my answer an explicit `return` is required if `module.uploadImage()` returns a promise that you want sequenced properly or if it returns a value that is needed by the next link in the promise chain.

Comment: sorry I mean Shadi's answer, return is missing but somehow it worked?

Comment: @user2727195 - If `module.uploadImage(data)` returns a promise that should be waited on before calling `module.requestInfo()` or if requestInfo needs results from `uploadImage()`, then Shadi's answer will not work properly.  If `module.requestInfo()` can be called anytime with no arguments and does not need to wait, then it will happen to work, though it is not proper coding.

Comment: Can I use `module.uploadImage.bind(null, data)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind says "The value to be passed as the this parameter to the target function when the bound function is called. The value is ignored if the bound function is constructed using the new operator." since module is exported from .js file in node

Comment: I suggested `module.uploadImage.bind(module, data)` because that will simulate `modue.uploadImage(data)` exactly (including setting `this` to be `module`) inside the `uploadImage()` function.  `module.uploadImage.bind(null, data)` will not set `this` the same way.  Sometimes that matters.  Sometimes it doesn't.  I prefer to always simulate exactly and then I don't have to "know" whether the value of `this` is being used or not in the called function.

Comment: question and it may not be part of the promises specs, each value returned by promises in chain, can it be available to use for the next, for example if first promise returns the `id` something and then in the next then i want to use that `id` to update, or should i use anonymous function approach?

Comment: @user2727195 - In a promise chain, the return value of a previous `.then()` handler (or it's resolve value if it returns a promise) is automatically passed as an argument to the next `.then()` handler.  That all happens automatically.  This is part of the promise specs.

Answer (score 0):

Use anonymous function:

```
fs.readFile('./img/thumbnail.png', function(error, data) {
module.create(body)
    .then(function(){ module.uploadImage(data); }) //expects collection.uploadImage(data);
    .then(module.requestInfo)
});
```